# RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration - During Iteration with iteritems on a defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator, runtime-error

While answering a particular question here in SO I stumbled upon a peculiar issue which I couldn't explain. Unfortunately the first two Google Search page returned one [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844837/how-to-fix-this-python-error-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-itera) Page which was also not helpful.

The Problem Code

```
>>> somedata=[random.randint(1,1000) for i in xrange(1,10000)]
>>> somehash=collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> for d in somedata:
    somehash[d]+=1      
>>> maxkey=0
>>> for k,v in somehash.iteritems():
    if somehash[maxkey] > v:
        maxkey=k            

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#700>", line 1, in <module>
    for k,v in somehash.iteritems():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
>>> for k,v in somehash.iteritems():
    if somehash[maxkey] > v:
        maxkey=k
>>>
```

And due to some odd reason, the first time I am iterating over the dictionary, Python is creating tantrums but the subsequent executions are fine as you can see in the example, the first time I iterated over the dictionary, it gave the Run Time Error but the next Time it didn't complain.

Any Idea what might be going wrong?

Just in case if required

```
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> sys.version
'2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]'

OS: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] (Windows 7)
```

Comment: The comparison `somehash[maxkey] > k` compares counts in the dict with hash values, which seems rather pointless.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Sven, it was a typo error. I will correct it. It should be `somehash[maxkey] > v`, and I am trying to iterate and determine the maximum value in the dictionary while only keeping track of the key.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding or deleting items of a dictionary while iterating over it is an error.  Since `somehash` is a `defaultdict`, even what seems like a read-only access in the line

```
if somehash[maxkey] > k:
```

might add a new key -- resulting in the error you encountered.

Comment: Specifically, the error is raised in the first iteration where `maxkey=0`. Your other keys come from the dict so they're already there.

Comment: That's the catch and using a normal dict would have raised a key error but this remained unnoticed.

Answer (score 6):

As Sven explained, the error you're running into is due to the way `defaultdict` works. When performing a lookup in a `defaultdict`, if the key doesn't already exist a default value is retrieved (hence the name) and the key is added to the dictionary (with the default value). This is the source of your `RuntimeError`.

You could do the following to avoid this problem:

```
for k, v in somehash.items():
    if somehash[maxkey] > v:
        maxkey = k
```

The main difference being that `somehash.items()` returns a list of (key, value) tuples, so you are actually iterating over that list and not `somehash` itself. The same goes for `.keys()` vs `.iterkeys()`.

Comment: Didn't work for me, had to explicitly materialize the items (worked via `list(the_dict.items())`) to stop the error. `.items()` returns a view of the dictionary, which per https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views reflect the changes in the underlying dictionary, thus probably causing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You are generating 9999 (somewhat) random integers *between 1 and 1000*, stored in `somedata`, which is used as a key for `somehash`, to store the occurrence of the numbers in somedata.

As `maxkey=0`, that key will never exist. As you are using a defaultdict, *[when each key is encountered for the first time, an entry is automatically created using the `default_factory` function which returns an empty list](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/defaultdict-examples.html)*, thus correctly throwing an error during iteration, in a manner that * FastTurtle*  already pointed out.

Use the `get` method to retrieve an item safely.

```
import random
import collections

somedata=[random.randint(1,1000) for i in xrange(1,10000)]
somehash=collections.defaultdict(int)
for d in somedata:
   somehash[d]+=1 

maxkey=0
for k,v in somehash.iteritems():
   if somehash.get(maxkey) > v:
       maxkey=k 
       print k,v
```

---

I see you are using Python 2.7, which has a new collection class called `Counter` , for counting hashable objects. Using `Counter` should be faster than the code above, and reduces your code to:

```
somedata=[random.randint(1,1000) for i in xrange(1,10000)]
somehash=collections.Counter(somedata)
```