# python RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Tags: python

I have obj like this

```
{hello: 'world', "foo.0.bar": v1, "foo.0.name": v2, "foo.1.bar": v3}
```

It should be expand to

```
{ hello: 'world', foo: [{'bar': v1, 'name': v2}, {bar: v3}]}
```

I wrote code below, splite by `'.'`, remove old key, append new key if contains `'.'`, but it said `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

```
def expand(obj):
    for k in obj.keys():
        expandField(obj, k, v)

def expandField(obj, f, v):
    parts = f.split('.')
    if(len(parts) == 1):
        return
    del obj[f]
    for i in xrange(0, len(parts) - 1):
        f = parts[i]
        currobj = obj.get(f)
        if (currobj == None):
            nextf = parts[i + 1]
            currobj = obj[f] = re.match(r'\d+', nextf) and [] or {}
        obj = currobj
    obj[len(parts) - 1] = v
```

for k, v in obj.iteritems():

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

Comment: And what is your question? Is the error not clear?

Comment: **Please search before you post** - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=RuntimeError%3A+dictionary+changed+size+during+iteration

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix this python error? RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844837/how-to-fix-this-python-error-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-itera)

Comment: @D.Shawley Ironically this question is now the first hit on Google when searching for the error message.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Like the message says: you changed the number of entries in obj inside of expandField() while in the middle of looping over this entries in expand.

You might try instead creating a new dictionary of the form you wish, or somehow recording the changes you want to make, and then making them AFTER the loop is done.

Comment: Yep, a new dictionary is the way to go. This also simplifies the recursion.

Answer (score 16):

You might want to copy your keys in a list and iterate over your dict using the latter, eg:

```
def expand(obj):
    keys = list(obj.keys())  # freeze keys iterator into a list
    for k in keys:
        expandField(obj, k, v)
```

I let you analyse if the resulting behavior suits your expected results.

**Edited** as per comments, thank you !

Comment: might work better with`keys = list(obj.keys())` which copies the keys into a list

Comment: `keys = obj.keys()` works nicely.  No need to add the memory overhead of converting to a list.

Comment: `keys = list(obj.keys())` is necessary if you delete any key of the dict while iterating over it (no matter if you iterate over the dict itself or using its keys). This is because `obj.keys()` returns just a view on the dict and thus reflects all changes done to the dict. Using the `list(...)` constructor will actually copy the keys to a new, independent list.

Answer (score 4):

For those experiencing

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

also make sure you're not **iterating through a `defaultdict`** when trying to access a non-existent key! I caught myself doing that inside the `for` loop, which caused the `defaultdict` to create a default value for this key, causing the aforementioned error.

The solution is to convert your `defaultdict` to `dict` before looping through it, i.e.

```
d = defaultdict(int)
d_new = dict(d)
```

or make sure you're not adding/removing any keys while iterating through it.

Comment: been scratching my head over this!

Comment: Ty. this was extremly helpfull, Was searching on wrong palces all the tim.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with wanting to change the dictionary's structure (remove/add) dicts within other dicts.

For my situation I created a deepcopy of the dict. With a deepcopy of my dict, I was able to iterate through and remove keys as needed.[Deepcopy - PythonDoc](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting this part

```
def expand(obj):
    for k in obj.keys():
        expandField(obj, k, v)
```

to the following

```
def expand(obj):
    keys = obj.keys()
    for k in keys:
        if k in obj:
            expandField(obj, k, v)
```

shall make it work.