# Delete keys of a dictionary whose values are empty lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary where some of the values corressponding to keys are empty lists. I want to delete all such keys

```
d = {'Receipt total': [], 'Total Amount (AED)': [], 'Grand total': [], 'Net Amount': [], 'Total': ['105.00'], 'Total (AED)': [], 'Total Invoice Amount': [], 'Invoice total': ['105.00'], 'Amount Due': ['0.00']}
```

Expected output:

```
d = {'Total': ['105.00'], 'Invoice total': ['105.00'], 'Amount Due': ['0.00']}
```

I tried:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    if value is None:
        del d[k]
```

My code is not working

Comment: What's the error message/traceback?

Comment: Should that be `key`instead of `k`?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: `[] is not None`

Comment: @Steve their code won't have reached that fault yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
new_d = dict((k,v) for k,v in d.items() if v)
```

And if you wish to overwrite `d` just change `new_d` to `d`.

There is some risk that might gives the wrong results:

`if v` when `v = []` will evaluate to Falsly, same as `0` so it might remove wrong key. In my answer I didn't address that. One can refer to the following link to understand better: [What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Comment: What if the original dictionary needs modifying?

Comment: @PeterWood You mean while iterating it? I only suggested a solution that returns the desired output.

Comment: The question said they wanted to delete keys.

Comment: @PeterWood I don't see a significant difference, this will "delete" the unwanted keys and return the desired solution. Most of the solutions are equivalent to what I suggested.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to note the risk of bugs in your answer.

Comment: @PeterWood This code served my purpose. What kind of bugs are you referring to?

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks, I added the problem that might happen. and a link to read more about truthy/falsly.

Comment: @DavidS that's not the problem I was talking about, although it's a good point

Comment: @M_Arora if you found yourself doing this more than a few times, you might think to give it a nice name, reduce duplication and extract it to a function, e.g. `def remove_empty_values(d):` This code wouldn't work. It doesn't modify `d`.

Comment: @PeterWood can you elaborate on what you refers?

Comment: @PeterWood Yes, I'll put it in a function because this ha to be done on multiple dictionaries but the logic worked

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) instead:

```
d = {'Receipt total': [], 'Total Amount (AED)': [], 'Grand total': [], 'Net Amount': [], 'Total': ['105.00'], 'Total (AED)': [], 'Total Invoice Amount': [], 'Invoice total': ['105.00'], 'Amount Due': ['0.00']}
    
d = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v != []}

print(d)

# d = {'Total': ['105.00'], 'Invoice total': ['105.00'], 'Amount Due': ['0.00']}
```

You'll probably want to explicitly check whether the value is `[]`. Otherwise, you may remove things that happen to evaluate to `False` ("falsey"), e.g. 0 values which you may not want. Of course, this point is only relevant if your dict could contain things other than lists as values.

Answer (score 3):

You can use dictionary comprehension like this:

```
d = {'Receipt total': [], 'Total Amount (AED)': [], 'Grand total': [], 'Net Amount': [], 'Total': ['105.00'], 'Total (AED)': [], 'Total Invoice Amount': [], 'Invoice total': ['105.00'], 'Amount Due': ['0.00']}

#use dictionary comprehensiion to create a new list of values where they value is not an empty list
d = {key : value for key, value in d.items() if len(value) != 0}

print(d)
```

Output : `{'Total': ['105.00'], 'Invoice total': ['105.00'], 'Amount Due': ['0.00']}`

By using a for loop to delete items of a dictionary, it will raise `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Answer (score 3):

You have at least three errors in your thinking.

The first is that an empty list is the same as `None`.

Only `None` is the same as `None`.

Secondly, comparing lists, you should use `==`. Using `is` to compare a list means that, even if a list has the same values in it, if it's not the actual same memory address, it won't compare equal.

Also, as you only want to know if the list is empty, you can use the fact that in Python, empty sequences are considered `False` and non-empty are considered `True`, so you can use a boolean conditional: `if not value:` which will be `True` for an empty list. If values can be something other than lists, then empty strings, zeroes, etc are all also `False`, so you might want to check more carefully.

Thirdly, you shouldn't modify the size of a container like a `dict` whilst iterating over it.
Either iterate over a copy of it, or create a record of things you want to modify, and then perform the modification afterwards.

The first way, iterating over a copy:

```
for key, value in list(d.items()):
    if not value:
        del d[key]
```

The second way, making a set of the keys to remove:

```
keys_to_remove = {key for key, value in d.items()
                  if not value}

for key in keys_to_remove:
    del d[key]
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with changing *values* of a dict while iterating it? Your statement sounds too general to me.

Comment: @KellyBundy sorry, when I said "shouldn't modify a container" I meant the structure of the container, i.e. the amount of values. Certainly, if values in a container are mutable, then you can modify them. Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the values are all lists, so you can use their truth, you could use [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress).

```
>>> dict(compress(d.items(), d.values()))
{'Total': ['105.00'], 'Invoice total': ['105.00'], 'Amount Due': ['0.00']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
d = {'Receipt total': [], 'Total Amount (AED)': [], 'Grand total': [], 'Net Amount': [], 'Total': ['105.00'], 'Total (AED)': [], 'Total Invoice Amount': [], 'Invoice total': ['105.00'], 'Amount Due': ['0.00']}

res = {}

for key, value in d.items():
    if value:
        res[key] = value

res
# {'Total': ['105.00'], 'Invoice total': ['105.00'], 'Amount Due': ['0.00']}
```

It is not recommended to delete items from a container during a for loop, better create a new one and add you need than delete from the original what you do not need.

For example:

```
a = [1,2,2,3]
for item in a:
    if item > 1:
        a.remove(item)
a
# [1, 2]
```

Leaves the second `2` because once you removed the first `2` you shifted indexes and your for loop has already checked index `1` but now your second `2` is at index `1` and it gets unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if v}
```

Answer (score -1):

The dictionary `d` you have is of type `Dict[str, List[str]]`. It is initialised in a way that means none of the values of the keys are `None`, but rather empty lists. For example:

```py
>>> listOfNothing = []

>>> print(listOfNothing)
[]

>>> print(type(listOfNothing))
<class 'list'>
```

If you want to check whether the *list* is empty (whether the value is an empty list), I'd suggest something like this:

```py
for key, value in d.items():
    if len(value) == 0:
        [do something]
```

However, as correctly pointed out by others, you can't change the size of the dictionary while iterating over it. This can be [solved by creating a new dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107676/python-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration).

Comment: An empty list is `False`-y: `if not value:`

Comment: Is it safe to modify a dictionary's keys whilst iterating over it?

Comment: @PeterWood You're right, edited my answer to include a link to a helpful StackOverflow question regarding that, as this question is really a two-in-one.