# How to fix "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" with python cpickle?

Tags: python, pickle, memory-address

I am working on trying to fix an 8 year old video game that was written by someone else with python 2.7.16. The main issue is that it crashes whenever it attempts to save.  Whenever it tries to pickle the data into a save file it crashes and creates an incomplete save file.

My second most recent error was a maximum recursion limit reached error. I patched that by increasing the recursion limit using the following.

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
```

I don't think it fixed whatever the underlying issue is though. Now I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I have tried to have the program print what is going into the pickle into the console but I got memory addresses rather than data.

It printed 
and 
A and B are memory addresses in hex that I don't particularly want to type out. But I can if I have to.

Here is the code where the issue is occurring.

```
     sys.setrecursionlimit(2000) #changing the recursion limit to see if it fixes cpickle.
     file = open(filename,"w")
        print self #Printing what will be pickled into a save to look for errors.
        try:  cPickle.dump(self,file)
        except MemoryError:
            print "DEBUGGING: cPickle failed, likely because of memory issue. Switching to regular pickle. Regular pickle is slower but less memory intensive."
            import pickle
            try:    pickle.dump(self,file)
            except: print "DEBUGGING: regular pickle also failed. The game was NOT saved"
            else:   print "game saved"
        except: 
            print "some weird error with cPickle - shown here:"
            cPickle.dump(self,file)
```

I expect to get the contents of self that would be saved and a "game saved" message if the save worked and for the program to continue.

The actual output is "
" then the path to the file and line where cpickle runs then "some weird error with cPickle - shown here:" then "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration" finally it crashes.

Edit:
New actual output after adding the following code to take a snapshot of self. Error now occurs in new code. selfCopy1 is what would be pickled now if it did not crash when it made the snapshot.

```
selfCopy1 = copy.deepcopy(dict(self))
print selfCopy1 
try: cPickle.dump(selfCopy1,file)
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

Comment: what you are dumping is more relevant to the question than how you are dumping. Just by this question's data, one can say that your dump variable is actually changing size due to some form of iteration.

Comment: Do any of the classes in your program define any of the methods listed at https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?#pickling-class-instances? That's the first place I'd look. If any of them add or remove items from a dictionary, they would definitely merit further investigation.

Comment: If what you are trying to dump/save is the game state, and that state is continuously updated even during the "save" call, there's a chance for race condition. Maybe take a snapshot of the `self` object and pickle that, instead of `self`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844837/how-to-fix-this-python-error-runtimeerror-dictionary-changed-size-during-itera

Comment: Try just `selfCopy1 = copy.deepcopy(self)` (no dict). That is how far my knowledge goes.